# Кодировка при перехвате смс ресивером - вместо руссских букв кракозябры

Tags: android, кодировка, java

При перехвате смс сообщений с помощью BroadcastReceiver, вместо русских букв в теле сообщения появляются кракозябры, а когда смс пишется английскими буквами все норм.

Подскажите, как реализовать нормальное отображение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кодировка символов в Android'е UTF-8 - используйте везде кодировку UTF-8 и все будет нормально.

Comment: Да, это я понял, а где именно надо указать кодировку?

Comment: А ты где видишь кракозябры? Если в отладчике, значит в IDE у тебя стоит кодировка не UTF-8. Поставь для начала в IDE кодировку UTF-8. А если будешь выводить на `TextView` то проблем не должно вообще возникать.